# Table rows growing to max?

Tags: html, css, html-table

```
<html>
<body style="background: white;">
<table style="height: 100%;width: 100%;">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <th>Column 1</th>
    <th>Column 2</th>
    <th>Column 3</th>
    <th>Column 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell 1</td>
    <td>Cell 2</td>
    <td>Cell 3</td>
    <td>Cell 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell 1</td>
    <td>Cell 2</td>
    <td>Cell 3</td>
    <td>Cell 4</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

results in:
[image: browser image]

(this is pasted in a new tab so there is no extra Css styling or anything going on)

How can I stop the rows from growing to their max height but rather to the content height?  (preferably without setting a fixed 20px height to the row)

Edit: I want to the table to still fill the whole page

Comment: `<table style="height: 100%;width: 100%;">` table has this, what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: I would'd like the table to grow to max height(100%) but have 'empty room' below the last row if there aren't enough rows to completely fill the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using flexboxes to achieve that:

```css
table,
tr {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

tbody {
  width: 100%;
}

th,
td {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<body style="background: white;">
  <table style="height: 100%; width: 100%">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th>Column 2</th>
        <th>Column 3</th>
        <th>Column 4</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Just be mindful that you'll be loosing some of the table features.

Answer (score 0):

> Height 100% is not required
> Remove it to take the minimum size table requires

Comment: well you're right but I'd like the table to be at 100% height. I just don't want the rows to grow to their max height.

Comment: Cells take up the  max available height of table